# How to configure Traefik ingressroute to route requests to a url?

Tags: routes, azure-aks, traefik, traefik-ingress, ingress-controller

I am trying to configure Traefik ingressRoute to route requests from a host to a url.
The host and traefik is setup in region1 while the url is for the loadbalancer in region2 pointing to services in region2. See my ingressroute configuration below:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: route-name
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`region1.domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        test-service:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://region2.domain.com/
```

I tried to follow the example here: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/ but I get the error:

```
IngressRoute in version "v1alpha1" cannot be handled as a IngressRoute: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.routes[0].services.test-service"
```

I am able to access the url for the loadbalancer in region2,so just wondering if it is possible/how to configure the Ingressroute to route request to the url?

Comment: there's a formatting issue in your IngressRoute definition, particularly in how you're specifying the service and its URL. In Traefik's IngressRoute, the services field under routes should be a list. Your definition attempts to directly include a loadBalancer under services, which is incorrect according to the Traefik IngressRoute CRD structure. Create an externalname service mentioning your region2 and update your ingress with this newly created service
` routes:
    - match: Host(`region1.domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: external-service`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to route requests from a Traefik IngressRoute in one region to a service or load balancer URL in another region, there are few different ways to achieve this.

option 1
create a Kubernetes Service of type `ExternalName` that points to your external URL. This service acts as a DNS alias to your external service.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: Yourregion2.domain.com
```

and update your IngressRoute to route requests to the ExternalName Service you just created.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: route-name
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`yourregion1.domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: external-service
          port: 80
```

[image]

This configuration assumes that requests to `region1.domain.com` will be routed to `region2.domain.com` through the `external-service`.
The `port` should match the port your external service listens on. Since we're pointing to a URL, `80` is used for HTTP, but adjust accordingly if your service uses HTTPS or another port.

Verify your service.

```
kubectl get svc external-service -n default
```

[image]

Test the routing by accessing `region1.domain.com` from a browser or using a tool like `curl`. You should be redirected to the service hosted at `region2.domain.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your response@Arko. I configured the ingressroute, externalName service and enabled externalName service in my traefik config in region1. I tested it using elasticsearch and kibana as the service behind the loadbalancer in region2. But got ```curl: Failed to connect to server``` error. There is no additional info in the logs of both traefik and elasticsearch. I tested that the region2 url works as I set up a traefik ingressroute to route to kibana service in region2 which it does, both on the browser and curl.  Tried to figure it out, not sure what else I am missing?

Comment: Traefik's configuration in region1 has the externalName service enabled right? Any firewalls between region1 and region2? 
Look at Traefik's access logs to see if the requests to the region1.domain.com are reaching Traefik and whether they are being routed correctly. If there are no logs for the requests, it could indicate a DNS resolution issue. Also what is the output if you do kubectl exec <Traefik pod> in region1 and run nslookup region2.domain.com.

Comment: By the way there is one more alternative way to achieve your requirement using [Traefik middlewear](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/overview/), specifically using the [ForwardAuth](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/#forwardauth "Permanent link") , and modify your IngressRoute to use the ForwardAuth middleware.
here's one [example](https://community.traefik.io/t/how-to-configure-middleware-with-kubernetes-ingress-middleware-xyz-does-not-exist/5016)

Comment: Thanks @Arko I was able to get it working using the externalName option. I just had to add a route for the host in region1 in the ingressroute I configured in region2 for it to be able to access the region2 service.